# REST API calls suddenly only return empty values

Tags: rest-api

I have a number of stable webforms which communicate with my Salesforce instance using the REST API using php CURL.  About 24 hours ago these calls - which have worked perfectly and unchanged for months - suddenly stopped working.  All of them.

On investigation I found that:

1. The authentication call works, and returns an access code as expected.
2. The subsequent call (usually a query to a Salesforce object to retrieve data) simply fails without returning anything - the return string is empty.
3. I tested with a simple API call (/sobjects/) and the webform again returned nothing while the same call using Workbench REST Explorer works.
4. I tested with v38 and v37 of the API with the same result.

I'm not sure what to try next.  There are a few possibilities I can think of:

1. I have run into a Salesforce resource limit.  This seems unlikely because it isn't a bulk API and my website volumes are low.
2. Salesforce has decided for some reason to block my website domain.  This seems unlikely because the authentication step works.

After that I am out of ideas so I am hoping that someone can suggest a way forward to identify and/or resolve this.

Comment: What form of encryption is your website negotiating? Could it be related to TLS v1 being disabled? Seems like an architecture or framework change (or lack thereof) rather than a code issue....